# SurfaceView: How to draw only small part of screen instead of entire screen

Tags: android, drawing, surfaceview, glsurfaceview

I want to have a static background image in my application, and then I want to have some small animations in the foreground. Currently, I have to basically redraw the entire screen every time even if the only thing that changed is small and only takes up a small part of the screen.

Is there a way to only update part of the screen to speed up my application framerate? Can it be done with SurfaceView, or do I have to use a GLSurfaceView instead?

Any explanations and links to tutorials/documentation would really be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: I easily get 60fps using SurfaceView and don't need a partial redraw. Just don't create any variables, objects or bitmaps or do any other unnecessary stuff in the main game loop.

Comment: I think I figured out how to do a partial redraw already. However, I think you're right. I'm thinking I need to more so restructure what I'm already doing to make the draw loop faster. However, now that I know how to do the partial redraw, I think I'll also add that in aside from clearing junk out of my draw loop. Thanks,

Comment: I am not sure that invalidate() works with SurfaceView. Last time I tried it did nothing. New mobiles are very fast, so for simple games you don't need openGL. Calculations are very fast and if() statements, so they are not a problem, but bitmap operations are slower, therefore it is best to set all varibales, objects and load bitmaps in the constructor or in onSizeChanged() where you can know the exact size of the SurfaceView.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `postInvalidate(int, int, int, int)` method (or just invalidate(...) if you're calling it from the UI thread). You can specify an area of the View to re-render, leaving the rest of the image untouched.

[Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidate%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: I see, So what you're saying is instead of having my "graphics" thread continuously draw. I should instead override the onDraw() method, and use invalidate(int,int,int,int) to draw the bit that I want. However, I would still need to keep track of my background and properly redraw that piece of hte background correct?

Comment: Currently I'm using drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, float left, float top, Paint paint) in the canvas class to draw this background at every call of my draw methods. Perhaps there is a way to only draw to the canvas a small portions of that bitmap to a small portion of my screen?